# Having trouble getting password_verify to verify hashed password

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following setup where I attempt to verify the user's password to log them in but I am stuck on the password verification.

The links to the database:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
$tablee='userstable';
```

The table structure:

```
users.userid int(11)
users.user_uid varchar(256)
users.user_pwd varchar(256)
users.user_perm int(5)
users.user_email varchar(256)
```

The form:

```
echo '<form action="'.getLogin($conn,$tablee).'" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uid">
<input type="password" name="pwd">
<input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" value="Login">
</form>';
```

The function:

```
function getLogin($conn,$tablee) {
if (isset($_POST['loginSubmit'])){
    $uid=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['uid']);
    $pwd=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pwd']);
    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT user_id,user_uid,user_pwd,user_perm,user_email FROM ".$tablee.".users WHERE user_uid=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$uid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $result=$stmt->bind_result($userid,$username,$userpassword,$permission,$email);
    $numrow=$stmt->num_rows;
    if ($numrow>0){
        $hashedPasswordCheck=password_verify($pwd,$userpassword);
        if ($hashedPasswordCheck==false) {
            header('Location: index.php?login=wrongpass&pwd='.$pwd.'&ps='.$userpassword.'&user='.$username.'&rows='.$stmt->fetch().'&id='.$userid.'&nr='.$numrow.'&em='.$email.'&length='.strlen($userpassword));
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
            exit();
        }
        elseif ($hashedPasswordCheck==true) {
            if ($stmt->fetch()){
                $_SESSION['id']=$userid;
                $_SESSION['perm']=$permission;
                header('Location: index.php?login=success');
                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();
                $conn->close();
                exit();
            }
            else {
                header('Location: index.php?login=whathappened');
            }
        }
        else {
            header('Location: index.php?login=nothingselected');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I added the GET parameters to see if something is wrong and I am getting back some odd results.  The userid, user email, user permission, the length of the hashed password, and the number of rows are returned.  However, the username and the hashed password are not.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

UPDATE:

Inserted the echo tag in the php file to avoid confusion with the form above.

And forgot to show how I store the password.  I am currently testing, so I just have a change password field.

The form:

```
echo '<form action="'.userCh($conn,$tablee).'" method="post">
<input type="password" name="editPassword">
<input type="submit" name="changePass" value="submit">
</form>';


function changePass($conn,$tablee){
if (isset($_POST['editPassword'])){
    $userid=$_SESSION['id'];
    $newPass=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['newch']);
    $hashedPwd=password_hash($newPass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql="UPDATE ".$tablee.".users SET user_pwd=? WHERE user_id=?;";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('si',$hashedPwd,$userid);
    $stmt->execute();
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

It turns out removing the lines that include `$stmt->store_result();`, `$numrow=$stmt->num_rows;`, `if (numrow>0){`, and its corresponding `}` did the trick.  But I still don't get why.  It works, but those four lines of code make sense to me.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Change the structure of your table and make user_pwd to char(60) to store exact hash values.

Comment: Your form action looks wrong.  Does that work? Aren't you supposed to have php opening and closing tags?. Better still get the table and connection variables from a configuration file.  Don't pass such important parameters via html form

Comment: @Akintunde Yes, it works.  Re: PHP this is inside an echo statement.  How would I get the table and connection variables from the config file? (Thanks for the heads up on that.)

Comment: @SaadSuri I still get the same results.

Comment: Show how you store passwords (register function). Please do not mangle input (escape), this may also be the reason you're having problems with password-verify. Do NOT only store 60 chars as the hash routine may change in the future, do not pass the password as a get param to the login page on wrong login (it will be in clear text, and even if it was wrong for your service it may be the users password for all other services)

Comment: Also, your `$tablee` variable in the db query seem to be the db name, you shouldn't need this unless you're using multiple databases.

Comment: There is no need for mysqli_real_escape_string in prepared Statements . Also do not escape passwords

Comment: @Jens I removed the `mysqli_real_escape_string` from the `$newPass=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['newch']);` and I reset the password and still get the same results.

Comment: @JimL Thanks, I am using multiple DBs.

Comment: @JimL I'm passing the parameters as GETs just for testing and debugging purposes.  I will remove that before I go live, thanks.  I reset the password field back to varchar(256), I just figured it was worth a shot even though all my strlen($userpassword) parameters came back as 60 anyway.

Comment: @Akintunde When you say I should get the table and connection variables from the config file are you suggesting I do something like this inside the function: `global $conn; global tablee;`?

Comment: Yeah that should work